# Is there any photography website where I could find photos based on exposure time, focal length, ISO...?

Tags: software, metadata

I was wondering if there is a site where I could filter photos that were shot, for example, with a certain exposure time and few other conditions.

Is there any photography website where I could filter the photos posted on the site by EXIF fields such as exposure time, focal length, ISO...?

Comment: For me this looks like XY problem. What is the end target? Because for example `f9` will give you totally different look on macro compared to landscape.

Comment: Do you want to filter *your own* photos, or find photos posted online *by others* who have used a particular setting? These are two very different questions.

Comment: @MichaelC posted by others. Accepted answer is exactly what I needed

Comment: So that would mean you are looking for photos by others? If so there is an obvious improvement that could be made to the question header so that is crystal clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flickr has some options available.  [This blog post](http://blog.michael-lowry.com/2008/01/flickr-exif-search-part-2.html) shows some hidden search options available. [This app](https://www.flickr.com/services/apps/72157603013068573/) gives statistics for your Flickr photos. And I know that it's possible to filter based upon camera model.

Comment: They still work, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Only does tags, aperture, and shutter speed, but you could use [Shutterdial](https://www.shutterdial.com/#/), which uses Flickr's API and images to show a filtered group of photos.